# How to migrate dockerfile maven plugin to gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am migrating from maven to gradle, but having trouble with one plugin. Here is the code:

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${registry}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}.${build.number}</tag>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

How can I change it to gradle? Is it possible to make it happen at gitlabl-ci.yml?

Comment: You might want to look at `jib`

Comment: [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin) is very nice, but does not use dockerfiles (it has its own way to configure the images). If you are migrating an existing project from Maven, the [bmushko' Docker plugin](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/) is probably more similar.